# Select a column from a data frame by a given name

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am writing a function, in this function, I would like to do something as following:

I have a data frame or list, I want to select a specific column by the given parameter in the function.

Example data

```
dat <- cbind.data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6))

function(dat, name = "B") {
 new_data <- dat[data$name ,]
 return(new_data)
}
```

what I would like to get is basically the column `dat$B`. My above function does not work as I expected. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subSET <- function(dat, name) {
 dat[name]
}

subSET2 <- function(dat, name) {
 dat[[name]]
}



subSET(dat, "B") # returns data.frame

  B
1 4
2 5
3 6

subSET2(dat, "B")  # returns vector
[1] 4 5 6
```